# Posicionar userform no mesmo monitor em que o excel está

Tags: vba, excel-vba

Boa tarde,

Estou criando um Dashboard no qual ao executar o Excel um userform é aberto, maximizado e o Excel é oculto.
Meu código funciona perfeitamente para um PC com apenas um monitor.

Ao usar um PC com dois monitores o VBA abre o userform no monitor principal, porém para maximizar ele pega as informações do monitor no qual o Excel estava aberto.

Alguém sabe como fazer o VBA identificar em qual monitor o Excel está aberto e abrir o userform nesse monitor?

```
'Set the Windows style so that the userform has a minimise and maximise button
lngCurrentStyle = GetWindowLong(lngHWnd, GWL_STYLE)
lngNewStyle = lngCurrentStyle Or WS_MINIMIZEBOX 'Or WS_MAXIMIZEBOX
lngNewStyle = lngNewStyle And Not WS_VISIBLE And Not WS_POPUP 'And WS_MINIMIZEBOX
SetWindowLong lngHWnd, GWL_STYLE, lngNewStyle

'Set the extended style to provide a taskbar icon
lngCurrentStyle = GetWindowLong(lngHWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE)
lngNewStyle = lngCurrentStyle Or WS_EX_APPWINDOW
SetWindowLong lngHWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, lngNewStyle
ShowWindow lngHWnd, SW_SHOW

'Remove a barra superior
HideTitleBar Me

'Maximiza o formulário
With Me
    .StartUpPosition = 1
    .Width = Application.Width
    .Height = Application.Height
    .Left = 0
    .Top = 0
End With
```

OBS: Não vou postar aqui o código completo por não ser um código muito complexo, porém, longo.

Obrigado a todos.

Answer (score 0):

#### Código

Você pode utilizar o seguinte código no Userform desejado:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    With Application
        Me.StartUpPosition = 0
        Application.WindowState = xlMaximized
        Me.Top = .Top
        Me.Left = .Left
        Me.Height = .Height
        Me.Width = .Width
    End With
End Sub
```

#### Explicação

Primeiro, escolhe a posição de início como manual com [StartUpPosition](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/startupposition-property)

Depois, maximiza o Excel com `Application.WindowState = xlMaximized`, pois ao trocar entre resoluções de monitores diferentes, o Excel não está maximizado e o tamanho do formulário não é o apropriado para aquele monitor.

E depois inicializa o formulário com as mesmas proporções do Excel:

```
Me.Top = .Top
Me.Left = .Left
Me.Height = .Height
Me.Width = .Width
```

Comment: Obrigado amigo, tinha acabado de modificar isso no meu código após ler algo similar em outro fórum, mas ainda não é o ideal. O ideal seria o programa ver que tem dois monitores e perguntar em qual ele deveria ser aberto. Será que tem como?

Comment: Encontrei uma maneira de realizar sem GPU, mas no meu não funcionou o teste. Porque a presença da placa de vídeo altera a programação dos monitores. Então o mais indicado seria abrir na aplicação Excel mesmo. Para GUIs mais avançadas, sugiro abandonar o VBA e partir para outras linguagens de programação.

Comment: Infelizmente não posso abandonar o excel.